# Foreach in BeginForm and display elements in RadioButtonFor() element

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using C#.NET MVC3 (Razor) to create a simple form. But in that form i need to print the content of a list in the form of radiobuttons. But i'm not sure how this works:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (Items item in Model.Items)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(item->itemId)
            @Html.LabelFor(item->description)
        </div>
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work.

I can probably use normal html tags to create the radio buttons. But then the data won't be auto saved in the right?

How can i make this work?

Comment: @archil It's not allowed to directly assign the 'item->property' like that. Normally i'd do --- (model => model.Property) --- But now i'm in a foreach loop and i need the data from 'item'. --- Right now it gives me the error: **No overload for method 'RadioButtonFor' takes 1 argument**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you using editor templates instead of writing those loops:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("Method", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Items)
}
```

and now define a corresponding editor template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the model (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ItemViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model ItemViewModel
<div>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.itemId, "1")
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.description)
</div>
```

Notice that you must pass a second argument to the `Html.RadioButtonFor` helper in addition to the lambda expression that picks the corresponding view model property. This argument represents the value that will be sent to the server and bound to the corresponding property if the user checks this radio button when the form is submitted.

Also notice that this works by convention. If we assume that the Items property in your main view model is of type `IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>` then the corresponding editor template that you must define and which will be rendered for each element of this collection is `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ItemViewModel.cshtml` or `~/Views/CurrentController/EditorTemplates/ItemViewModel.cshtml` if you don't want this template to be shared between multiple controllers.

Answer (score 2):

As you are inside foreach loop. following will work.

```
foreach (Items item in Model.Items)
{
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(item.itemId)
        @Html.LabelFor(item.description)
    </div>
}
```

If you want to save them all you need to implement zero index based solution as follows

```
@{int i = 0}
foreach (Items item in Model.Items)
{
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model =>model[i].itemId)
        @Html.LabelFor(model =>model[i].description)
    </div>
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is a bit different:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.ItemId)
@Html.LabelFor(model => item.Description)
```

Everything else looks fine.

[EDIT] Whoa, I must be tired. Yeah, the following looks just fine, but only for **display**. Check the Darin's answer for editor template.

[EDIT2] It's not quite obvious from the question, but it seems from your comments that the `item` in the foreach is another Enumerable. Nest the foreach loops then, to display the properties:

```
@foreach(var itemList in Model.Items)
{
    foreach(var item in itemList)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.ItemId)
            @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Description)
        <div>
    }
}
```

Is that *it*? I'm still not sure if I understand it correctly. :)

Comment: I know, but this time i'm in a foreach loop. My model has a IEnumerable list and i'm going through that in the foreach loop. I need to display the data from the IEnumerable in the radio buttons for each item it finds. Any idea?

Comment: Assuming each of the `item`s in the loop is a class with `ItemId` and `Description`, your version - corrected for the syntax - should be OK.